# Regex validate a String that has no new line character - Ignore if string has new line (\n)

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate a string if it does not contain a new line.

for Eg:
**string 1:** "adsfasdfasdf" - should say true

**string 2:** "asdfasdfsd

asdfasdfas" should return false (i don't want string which has a new line)

**string 3:** "asdf efgh" should say true (string has space needed, need to ignore if it has new line or tab)

**my regex** - `/^\S+$/` // this consider tab along with new line... I tried \N but no help... I want to validate the new line, not tab space.

```js
const regE = new RegExp(/^\S+$/g);
console.log("working", regE.test("Asdfasdf"));
console.log("working", regE.test("asdfasd\n\n\nasdf"));
console.log("not working", regE.test("Asdfasasdfsa dfasdfsdfd"));
```

Comment: Everything but a newline: `^[^\n]*$`. Anything but a line break: `^.*$` - dot does not match line breaks by default.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for: `/^[^\r\n\f\v]+$/g`

`\S` is equal to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`. So you only need to remove the `\t` which is for tab and the whitespace.

You can see the explanations at the right on this example: https://regex101.com/r/cc1Hu8/1

Answer (score 0):

I added a match group around your "any non-whitespace char" and added a space to that again.

```
^    //start of line
 [   //start group
  \S //match any non-whitespace character
  .  //match character except new line
 ]+  //match group one or more times
 $   //end of line
```

```js
const regE = new RegExp(/^[\S.]+$/g);
console.log("Should be true, it is", regE.test("Asdfasdf"));
console.log("Should be false, it is", regE.test("asdfasd\n\n\nasdf"));
console.log("Should be true, it is", regE.test("Asdfasasdfsa dfasdfsdfd"));
```